# VLOOKUP with multiple criteria not working correctly

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I am currently trying to run a `VLOOKUP` that has has multiple criteria. I am to use a `MAX(IF())` function to get the maximum value based on a certain criteria. Here is my code:

`IF(AND(SUM(COUNTIF(A7,{"*500*"})),SUM(COUNTIF(A7,{"*Total*"}))),VLOOKUP(MAX(IF(Page1!$B$2:$B$24053=Sheet2!A6,Page1!$Z$2:$Z$24054)),Page1!$Z$2:$AA$24053,2,TRUE),"-")`

Everything in the formula works except for the first part of the `VLOOKUP`with the `MAX(IF())` function. It basically keeps saying the `IF` statement is `FALSE` even when it is true.

Comment: Try [multiple criteria Index/Match](https://www.deskbright.com/excel/index-match-multiple-criteria/).  Without knowing what your data looks like, it's hard to help troubleshoot your formula.  Have you stepped through with the Evaluate Formula tool? (In Data tab, click "Evaluate Formula").  Also, why do you have `500` and `Total` in brackets?

Comment: That's an array formula. Are you array-entering it by pressing `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`?

Answer (score -1):

When vlookup and hlookup hit their limit. Then you need to use index and match.

Comment: Can you explain to OP how to do this?

Comment: I always have to look it up (I don't do spread sheets much). If someone else does a better answer with example, Then I will upvote it and remove mine.